# Deleting Backbone views and associated DOM elements

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events

My code structure is as follows:

```
hTrackView contains:  
    measureView contains:  
        //several instatianted views, not stored in a collection or an array  
        measureRepView0,  
        measureRepView1,  
        ...
```

The measureRepViews (mRVs) have many variables on them, some of which are shared with other instances of mRVs.

Our issue arises when we add, delete, or edit one of the shared variables, as per the following situations:

- We delete one of the mRVs, and the rest remain unchanged and in the same order without the deleted one.
- We add a mRV and it is appended to the other mRVs.
- We change one of the shared 'global' variables and all mRVs rerender with the new variable representations.

We have seen examples that include `bind()` and `bindAll()`, so in the parent measureView's init we implemented this:

```
initialize: function(options){
    // Given a list of variables 'options', set the variables of this to those of options
    // e.g. this.x = options.x
    if (options) {
        for (var key in options) {
            this[key] = options[key];
        }

        this.el = '#measure-container-'+options.parent.cid;
    }

    this.newMeasureRepViews = [];

    _.bindAll(this, 'render');
    this.listenTo(this.measureRepresentations, 'remove', _.bind(this.render, this));  
    this.listenTo(this.measureRepresentations, 'add', _.bind(this.render, this));  
    this.model.on('change:scale', _.bind(this.render, this));
    this.collectionOfMeasures.on('add', _.bind(this.render, this));
    this.collectionOfMeasures.on('remove', _.bind(this.render, this));

    this.render();
}
```

There may be competing philosophies or code structures in this program, sorry, we are learning. The real problem occurs when we add or delete and the DOM updates correctly, however we lose track of the Backbone View objects themselves.   For example, starting with a clean slate, we have one mRV with a cid of 26 (we pull this from the view itself and put it in the id on the DOM)..  Then we add a mRV, and now we have 'c55' and 'c57'   I am fine with the fact that Backbone deleted the 26, because it reinstantiated a 55 version of it.  However, when we tried to manipulate 55, it came up with an undefined error. We traced this back to being an issue with a property of that specific mRV, and noticed that there were 3 Backbone Views in the application [26, 55, 57] (where there should have been two [55, 57]).   So how would I set it up properly to delete BOTH the Backbone View and the DOM representation given the three situations (add, delete, changeall)?

For reference:

In measureView.js:

```
render: function(){
     var compiledTemplate = _.template( MeasureTemplate, measureTemplateParameters );

     // If we are adding a rep, clear the current reps, then add the template
     while(this.newMeasureRepViews.length >0) {
        var deleting = this.newMeasureRepViews.pop();
        deleting.stopListening();
        delete deleting;
     }

     // I'm assuming this isn't correct, and the DOM should be coupled to the View, so that when the View is deleted the DOM is as well.
     // Maybe we call this.destroy() or this.remove() here?
     $(this.el).html(''); // clear the html
     // append the new completed compiled template
     $(this.el).append( compiledTemplate )

     ...
  }
```

To recap, I am wondering

1. Can the current code structure accomplish what I'm trying to do with deleting/adding/changing views?
2. Do we use destroy() or remove()?

Comment: If you are working with a lot of nested views, using a framework such as Backbone.Marionette will make your life profoundly more enjoyable.